# Does "match ... true -> foo | false -> bar" have special meaning in Ocaml?

Tags: syntax, switch-statement, pattern-matching, ocaml

I encountered the following construct in various places throughout Ocaml project I'm reading the code of.

```
match something with
  true -> foo
  | false -> bar
```

At first glance, it works like usual `if` statement.  At second glance, it.. works like usual `if` statement!  At third glance, I decided to ask at SO.  Does this construct have special meaning or a subtle difference from `if` statement that matters in peculiar cases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, it's an if statement.

Often `match` cases are more common in OCaml code than `if`, so it may be used for uniformity.

Comment: I agree but I would put it another way: I think programming in ML makes you see patterns to match everywhere after a while, so that you write "match x with" first and start thinking after that.

Comment: Not only is it equivalent to an if statement, it's quite likely that all if statements get desugared in this way by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with the previous answer, it DOES the work of an if statement but it's more flexible than that.

"pattern matching is a switch statement but 10 times more powerful" someone stated

take a look at this tutorial explaining ways to use pattern matching [Link here](http://translate.google.fr/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&u=http://laurent.le-brun.eu/site/index.php/2007/11/14/8-l06-pattern-matching&sl=fr&tl=en&history_state0=&swap=1)

Also, when using OCAML pattern matching is the way to allow you break composed data to simple ones, for example a list, tuple and much more

```
  > Let imply v = 
    match v with 
     | True, x -> x 
     | False, _ -> true;; 

  > Let head = function 
   | [] -> 42 
   | H:: _ -> am;

  > Let rec sum = function 
   | [] -> 0 
   | H:: l -> h + sum l;;
```

Comment: Thank you for useful examples and a good reminder for those who learn OCaml.  My question, however, was not about using `match` in general, but about a particular use of it, when a boolean value is matched against `true` and `false` only.  In such cases it indeed works as `if` operator.  David's answer and subsequent comments explain this.